# SQL Distinct Count from a certain date range?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Have set up a query for my table where I would like to display certain reactions left within the previous weeks period, this works well when I write

```
SELECT * 
FROM reactiondata 
WHERE reaction_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
ORDER BY reaction_time ASC;
```

And also this query selects the unique promo ID fields and distinct usernames so you can see how many unique usernames have been sent which promo ID.

```
SELECT 
   reaction_promoID, 
   COUNT( DISTINCT reaction_username) AS reaction_username  
FROM reactiondata GROUP BY reaction_promoID
```

However, I would like it so the second query works within a date range for the last week, like the first one does.  When I add Where etc... to the query it does not work.

Any help hugely appeciated!

A+TS

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT reaction_promoID, COUNT( DISTINCT reaction_username) AS reaction_username  
FROM reactiondata 
WHERE reaction_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY reaction_promoID
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you!  Won't let me accept your answer for some reason!

Comment: @user3065453: You can accept an answer 15 minutes after you asked your question, not before.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is time for HAVING clause:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

```
SELECT reaction_promoID, COUNT( DISTINCT reaction_username) AS reaction_username  
FROM reactiondata 
GROUP BY reaction_promoID
HAVING  reaction_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: sounds awesome, but sadly it came up unknown column 'reaction_time' when it definitely exists in the table.

Comment: Ah, could be that you have to include reaction_time in the list of columns you SELECT.